# How to generate event handlers with loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

For example, I have 10 a tags generated from an AJAX response:

```
<a href="#" id="b1">b1</a>
<a href="#" id="b2">b2</a>
<a href="#" id="b3">b3</a>
<a href="#" id="b4">b4</a>
<a href="#" id="b5">b5</a>
<a href="#" id="b6">b6</a>
<a href="#" id="b7">b7</a>
<a href="#" id="b8">b8</a>
<a href="#" id="b9">b9</a>
<a href="#" id="b10">b10</a>
```

I need to assign onclick event to each of them via loop:

```
for(i=1; i<11; i++) {
    document.getElementById("b"+i).onclick=function() {
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, it only assigns onclick to the last a tag and alerts "11". How can I get this to work? I'd prefer not to use jQuery.

Comment: You should call `attachEvent` / `addEventListener`  (although they won't solve your problem)

Comment: @SLaks Why are `attachEvent`/`addEventListener` more appropriate than `element.onclick`?

Comment: @MicahHenning: To allow you to have multiple handlers.

Comment: @SLaks Ah, good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

All of your handlers are sharing the same `i` variable.

You need to put each handler into a separate function that takes `i` as a parameter so that each one gets its own variable:

```
function handleElement(i) {
    document.getElementById("b"+i).onclick=function() {
        alert(i);
    };
}

for(i=1; i<11; i++) 
    handleElement(i);
```

Comment: test.html:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Answer (score 20):

A closure is what you're looking for:

```
for(i=1; i<11; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        document.getElementById("b"+i).onclick=function() {
            alert(i);
        };
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: I'd say that Caballero has a closure where they don't want one and that they want a closure buster to force the immediate evaluation of `i`. That's what your self-executing function is doing.

Comment: Closure/No-Closure... I don't care! This anonymous/self-invoking solution is beautiful :)  I'd have ticked this one.

Comment: Far more elegant than having a separate function.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to use closure on this problem. The idea is to create a scope with a snapshot of "i" variable for each iteration to be used by event handler.

Solution #1 (as was mentioned by Kevin):

```
for(i=1; i<11; i++) {
    (function(num) {

       document.getElementById("b"+num).addEventListener('click', function() {
            alert(num);
       });

    })(i);
}
```

Solution #2:

```
for (i=1; i<11; i++) {
    document.getElementById("b"+i).addEventListener('click', (function(){
        var num = i;
        return function() {
            alert(num);
        }
    })());
}
```