# Setting event handlers using a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures, dom-events

I was messing around with some javascript, on jsfiddle, and ran into a strange issue. I can't seem to figure out why I am unable to set `onclick` event handlers via a for loop:

html:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" width="500">
    <tr id="headerRow">
        <td>Header1</td>
        <td>Header2</td>
        <td>Header3</td>
        <td>Header4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>books</td>
        <td>red</td>
        <td>peas</td>
        <td>321</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>tapes</td>
        <td>blue</td>
        <td>jello</td>
        <td>654</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js executed in DOM ready:

```
var arr = document.getElementById('headerRow')
    .getElementsByTagName("td");

// Why does this work??
/*arr[0].onclick = function() { alert(arr[0].innerHTML); };
arr[1].onclick = function() { alert(arr[1].innerHTML); };
arr[2].onclick = function() { alert(arr[2].innerHTML); };
arr[3].onclick = function() { alert(arr[3].innerHTML); };
*/

//But this doesn't????
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].onclick = function() { alert(arr[i].innerHTML); };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xzmMj/4/

Comment: Thinks this is the same as what you're looking for?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487366/how-to-generate-event-handlers-with-loop-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i` will not contain the "current index" like you are intending, but rather the last value `i` was, ie `arr.length`

One quick n dirty solution would be to do something like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    (function(_i){
        arr[_i].onclick = function() { alert(arr[_i].innerHTML); };
    })(i);
}
```

what this does is captures the current value of `i` in a new variable `_i` within the closure of the statement you're executing, so it'll stay around and be the value you'd expect every time your onclick handler is called.

Comment: Interesting.. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need a closure, otherwise the `arr[i]` executes in an alternate scope and blows up.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    arr[i].onclick = function(text) { 
        return function () {
            alert(text); 
        };
    }(arr[i].innerHTML);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xzmMj/5/

Comment: Cool, thanks. Makes sense. I'll have to get more friendly with "Closures"

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error. `i` is a global variable that you're incrementing in the for loop. When the loop finishes, i will be equal to 4. Then in your click handler function, you're trying to display `arr[i].innerHTML`, which is now `arr[4].innerHTML`. `arr[4]` obviously doesn't exist, so you get an error.

For an easy fix, change `alert(arr[i].innerHTML)` to `alert(this.innerHTML)`. `this`, in the context of the click handler function, will refer to the `<TD>` element.