# javascript - removeAttribute for onclick and addEventListener in a loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures, addeventlistener

Dealing with a particular case where there are a number of elements with inline `onclick` event triggers that also pass a variable that need to be preprocessed through an `addEventListener` with the original `onClick` removed, preferably through `removeAttribute` as opposed to `setAttribute("onclick", null)`.

```
<div onClick="alert('shoe');">shoe</div>
<div onClick="alert('epic');">epic</div>
<div onClick="alert('dogs');">dogs</div>
<div onClick="alert('army');">army</div>
```

For the sake of reuse and usefulness to others - the example above is simplified however there is no need to handle IE `attachEvent` or `detachEvent` and jQuery is not available (for me at least).

I've tried several approaches and my initial trial code looked like the following:

```
var fields = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        word = fields[i].getAttribute("onClick").substr(7,4);
        fields[i].addEventListener("click", function() {console.log(word);}, false);
        fields[i].removeAttribute("onclick");
    }
```

Needles to say in most derivative approaches i've either managed to remove the `onclick` but couldn't assign the event listener, could populate a words array but only with the last word and so forth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate event handlers with loop in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487366/how-to-generate-event-handlers-with-loop-in-javascript)

Comment: indeed, thank you @FelixKling - that article you pointed to is somewhat helpful for this situation and i've looked on it several times before posting this question... essentially, what i think i'm dealing with (despite a lack of understanding of proper syntax and how dom methods work) is once i've made an array of element pointers i don't really know how to get each element's attribute, parse that attribute and assign each element (individually) an `addEventListener` with the previously parsed attribute...

Comment: i've tried local loop procedure to parent array push to the point of using either several functions or closures within closures and all i end up with is only partially useful and breaks... i'm clueless as to a solution at this point.

Comment: You can do it like in the accepted answer: Create a function and put the code your currently have in the loop body in the function. Call the function in the loop and pass the element as argument. Like `function bindHandler(element) { var word = element.getAttribute.... } ...  for (....) { bindHandler(fields[i]); }`

Comment: Managed to come up with a solution and my main error was not passing the right variable to the closure and indeed it was the solution i was looking for. Made a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/GhPKq/ for anyone looking for insight to the same problems. Also thanks for your effort @FelixKling.