# Convert js function to inline onclick

Tags: javascript

I have this great function which toggles class with pure javascript just like i want to:

```
// hasClass
function hasClass(elem, className) {
    return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + elem.className + ' ');
}
// toggleClass
function toggleClass(elem, className) {
    var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace( /[\t\r\n]/g, " " ) + ' ';
    if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
        while (newClass.indexOf(" " + className + " ") >= 0 ) {
            newClass = newClass.replace( " " + className + " " , " " );
        }
        elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    } else {
        elem.className += ' ' + className;
    }
}
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    toggleClass(this, 'active');
}
```

I tried to convert it to inline onclick function by **removing this part**:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    toggleClass(this, 'active');
}
```

**And adding**:

```
onclick="toggleClass(this, 'active')"
```

To my element, but **i guess i'm doing something wrong** and it doesn't function at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: *"...it doesn't function..."* is quite vague. What error(s) do you get? Have you looked in the web console?

Comment: Why do you want inline function? It is bad practice. And `onclick` as well. Look into `addEventListener`, that's the proper modern way of attaching events.

Comment: The reason i want inline function is i want to use the same function on a lot of different elements. i think it's easier that way? am i wrong?

Comment: If you want to use the same function on a lot of different elements, then thats a lot easier to do the first way: just use a loop.  You have to be careful about scope, but it's way better than copying-and-pasting the attribute string zillions of times in the HTML

Comment: Seems to be working fine http://jsbin.com/genimo/3/edit

Comment: Seems like what you need is event delegation.

Comment: Oh Thanks Eugene. that's weird it wasn't working in jsfiddle for some reason... Great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, `toggleClass` isn't a global. `onXyz` attribute event handlers can only access global functions. It's one of the several reasons **not** to use them.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called closures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Also this topic might be useful: [How to generate event handlers with loop in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487366/how-to-generate-event-handlers-with-loop-in-javascript)