# Accessing JSON API via node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, bitcoin

I'd like to access the JSON on

```
"https://blockchain.info/tx-index/"+txs[i]+"?format=json"
```

But each time I try to access it with the request, http, or https modules, I can never seem to get any information. The callback is never called, and as near as I can tell, the function doesn't return anything.

Since I'm apparently an idiot in javascript, can you help me out?

Edit: I also tried another method described on here, but it doesn't seem to work either. It always returns undefined.

```
function httpGet(url)   {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,false);
    xmlHttp.send();
    return xmlHttp.resonpose;
}
```

Edit: Full loop code:

```
        index = 0;
        txs = info.x.txIndexes;
        for (i = 0; i < txs.length; i++)    {
            console.log(i);
            request.get("https://blockchain.info/tx-index/"+txs[i]+"?format=json&cors=true", function(error,response,body)  {
                console.log("body");
                txs[index] = JSON.parse(body);
                index++;
            });
            var time = Date.now() + 1000;
            while (Date.now() < time)
                var a = true;
            txs[i] = txt;
        }
```

Comment: I've tried several different versions. I'll post the most recent.

Comment: I have actually loaded said module. Every time I try to use it it returns undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> function httpGet(url)   {
>     var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
>     xmlHttp.open("GET",url,false);
>     xmlHttp.send();
>     return xmlHttp.resonpose;
> }
> ```

`resonpose` is spelt [`response`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-response-attribute), but the more generally useful property name is [`responseText`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-responsetext-attribute).

---

Your attempt to use `request.get` is failing for a completely different reason, but that is covered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487366/how-to-generate-event-handlers-with-loop-in-javascript) as your load event handler is using the wrong value for `i`.

Comment: Whoops, transcription typo :)

Comment: Weird. Returning response results in undefined. Returning responseText results in the correct result. Thank you!