# Javascript, html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I created a table dynamically from an input field using Javascript. If the user put in 3 and click on go, a table is created with 3 rows.

I used the `.keyup` function to target a cloumn and it worked. The problem is that `var x = $("#inputfieldid").val()` returns only value for the last row while other rows return empty.

```js
/*creating the table dynamically*/
  function createTable() {
    var a = document.getElementById('course_no').value;
    var level = document.getElementById('level').value;
    var semester = document.getElementById('semester').value;
    if (a === "" || level==="" || semester==="" || isNaN(a)===true) {
      alert("OOPs...","Please make sure you select level, semester and enter the number of courses","error");
    } else {
      $("#select_this").hide();
      $("#table_result").show();
      var th = document.querySelectorAll('#table th');//To check whether `TD` is appended in table or not!
      if (!th.length) {
        //If not appended, then append TD in table
        var rows = "<th><p><h4>S/N</h4></p></th><th><p><h4>COURSE CODE</h4></p></th><th><p><h4>COURSE UNIT</h4></p></th><th><p><h4>SCORE</h4></p></th><th><p><h4>GRADE</h4></p></th>";
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.innerHTML = rows;
        document.getElementById("table").appendChild(table.firstChild);
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        var rid = i + 1;
        var elems = '';
        elems += "<tr><td><p><b>"+rid+"</b></p></td><td><p><b><input class='form-control' type='text' name='" + "course_code".concat(i + 1) + "' id='" + "course_code".concat(i + 1) + "'></b></p></td><td><p><b><input class='form-control' type='text' name='" + "course_unit".concat(i + 1) + "' id='" + "course_unit".concat(i + 1) + "'></b></p></td><td><p><b><input class='form-control' type='text' name='" + "score".concat(i + 1) + "' id='" + "score".concat(i + 1) + "'></b></p></td><td><p><b><input class='form-control' type='text' readonly name='" + "grade".concat(i + 1) + "' id='" + "grade".concat(i + 1) + "'></b></p></td></tr>";
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.innerHTML = elems;
        document.getElementById("table").appendChild(table.firstChild);
      }

          /*checking out the result on click function*/
    //var a = document.getElementById('course_no').value;
      for (var i = 0; i < a; i++){
        var ade = i + 1;
        $("#course_code".concat(i + 1)).keyup(function() {
          var course = document.getElementById("input#course_code".concat(ade)).value;
          console.log(course);
        })
      }

    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-8">
        <p><h3>My School Result</h3></p>
        <p>Please enter the number of courses in the box below</p>
        <hr>
        <div id="result">
          <div id="select_this">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="course_number">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="level" class="col-md-4 control-label"><p>Level</p></label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                  <select name="level" id="level" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">SELECT LEVEL</option>
                    <option value="100 LEVEL">100 LEVEL</option>
                    <option value="200 LEVEL">200 LEVEL</option>
                    <option value="300 LEVEL">300 LEVEL</option>
                    <option value="400 LEVEL">400 LEVEL</option>
                    <option value="SPILL OVER">SPILL OVER</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="semester" class="col-md-4 control-label"><p>Semester</p></label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                  <select name="semester" id="semester" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">SELECT SEMESTER</option>
                    <option value="FIRST SEMESTER">FIRST SEMESTER</option>
                    <option value="SECOND SEMESTER">SECOND SEMESTER</option>
                    <option value="FIRST SEMESTER SPILL">FIRST SEMESTER SPILL</option>
                    <option value="SECOND SEMESTER SPILL">SECOND SEMESTER SPILL</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="course_no" class="col-md-4 control-label"><p>Number of Courses</p></label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="course_no" name="course_no" placeholder="How many courses did you want to create result for?">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="course_message"></div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                  <button type="button" onclick='createTable()' id="loop_course" class="btn btn-default">GO -></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div id="table_result" style="display: none;">
            <form>
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="table" class="order-table table" name="table1" required>

                </table>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Submit Result</a>
                <p></br></p>
                <p></br></p>
                <p></br></p>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate event handlers with loop in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487366/how-to-generate-event-handlers-with-loop-in-javascript)

Comment: And possibly also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself". Also review the part about writing titles. Your current title does not describe your question at all.

Comment: Done that @Chris Happy. sorry devs I am new on this platform

Answer (score 0):

Use just Jquery:

```
      $('td[id^="course_code"]').on('keyup', function(){
        // Get the next td
        var nextTd = $(this).next('td');
        // Get the Text inside of this td
        var val = $('input[id^="course_code"]', nextId).val()
        });
```

to Loop on all TD of the table:

```
 $('#table_result tr').each(function() { 
var course = $(this).find('td[id^="course_code"]').html(); 
});
```

Comment: @Frenchi In LA, i tried that but its giving error in the console student-result:253 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. it is pinting to $("td[id^=\'course_code\'"]).on("keyup", function(){

Comment: I want to get the values of each input fields on the console

Comment: I rewrite the code. I didn't test it before, but It jsut gives you some idea to get all DOM then you can check values or loop etc.

Comment: fixed the earlier error i comented about, but its not showing anything on the DOM.