# Adding an onclick function to several similar buttons that shows/hides corresponding element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

The html is something like this:

```
<main class="wrapper">
    <section>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-green">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <div class="dropbtn">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">Edit</a>
                        <a href="" class="fa fa-times">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-white icon-lg"></i>
                <h2>Line #1</h2>
                <p>Available</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3>Lorem Ipsum.</h3>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <button type="button" class="card-btn">Reserve Now!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-green">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <div class="dropbtn">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">Edit</a>
                        <a href="" class="fa fa-times">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-white icon-lg"></i>
                <h2>Line #2</h2>
                <p>Available</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3>Lorem Ipsum.</h3>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <button type="button" class="card-btn">Reserve Now!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-red">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <div class="dropbtn">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">Edit</a>
                        <a href="" class="fa fa-times">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-white icon-lg"></i>
                <h2>Line #3</h2>
                <p>In Use</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3>Lorem Ipsum.</h3>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <button type="button" class="card-btn">Reserve Now!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-red">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <div class="dropbtn">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">Edit</a>
                        <a href="" class="fa fa-times">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-white icon-lg"></i>
                <h2>Line #4</h2>
                <p>In Use</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3>Lorem Ipsum.</h3>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <button type="button" class="card-btn">Reserve Now!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-red">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <div class="dropbtn">
                        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">Edit</a>
                        <a href="" class="fa fa-times">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-white icon-lg"></i>
                <h2>Line #5</h2>
                <p>In Use</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3>Lorem Ipsum.</h3>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <p class="card-text">Nulla vitae libero, </p>
                <button type="button" class="card-btn">Reserve Now!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

The jquery code is something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    var btnSelector = ".dropdown:eq(" + i + ") .dropbtn";
    var drpSelector = ".dropdown:eq(" + i + ") .dropdown-content";

    $(btnSelector).on("click", function(event){
        if($(".dropdown:eq(0) .dropdown-content").is(":visible")){
            $(".dropdown:eq(0) .dropdown-content").hide();
        }
        else{
            $(".dropdown:eq(0) .dropdown-content").show();
        }
    });
}
```

which is thought to get the nth button with the class *".dropbtn"*, adding a function to it which shows or hides the nth dropdown-menu container with the class *".dropdown-content"*. Both of which are in the class *".dropdown"* hence why .eq() is used on the dropdown instead of dropdown-content class. But when it is run, only the fifth dropdown-content is shown/hidden using any button. But when hardcoded, meaning something like this:

```
$(".dropdown:eq(0) .dropbtn").on("click", function(event){
    if($(".dropdown:eq(0) .dropdown-content").css("display") == "none"){
        $(".dropdown:eq(0) .dropdown-content").css("display","block");
    }
    else{
        $(".dropdown:eq(0) .dropdown-content").css("display","none");   
    }
});

$(".dropdown:eq(1) .dropbtn").on("click", function(event){
    if($(".dropdown:eq(1) .dropdown-content").css("display") == "none"){
        $(".dropdown:eq(1) .dropdown-content").css("display","block");
    }
    else{
        $(".dropdown:eq(1) .dropdown-content").css("display","none");   
    }
});

$(".dropdown:eq(2) .dropbtn").on("click", function(event){
    if($(".dropdown:eq(2) .dropdown-content").css("display") == "none"){
        $(".dropdown:eq(2) .dropdown-content").css("display","block");
    }
    else{
        $(".dropdown:eq(2) .dropdown-content").css("display","none");   
    }
});

$(".dropdown:eq(3) .dropbtn").on("click", function(event){
    if($(".dropdown:eq(3) .dropdown-content").css("display") == "none"){
        $(".dropdown:eq(3) .dropdown-content").css("display","block");
    }
    else{
        $(".dropdown:eq(3) .dropdown-content").css("display","none");   
    }
});

$(".dropdown:eq(4) .dropbtn").on("click", function(event){
    if($(".dropdown:eq(4) .dropdown-content").css("display") == "none"){
        $(".dropdown:eq(4) .dropdown-content").css("display","block");
    }
    else{
        $(".dropdown:eq(4) .dropdown-content").css("display","none");   
    }
});
```

it is properly showing corresponding dropdowns for the specific buttons. Can I ask for help regarding how to fix this? I need this not to be hardcoded since currently it isn't sure how many dropdowns like this is needed for the site.

Comment: Your problem is the "infamous loop issue", but the solution is to not use a loop at all, but instead traverse the DOM, however as no markup is posted, we can't help you with that.

Comment: Traversing the DOM, I see, thank you for the comment, will research on that right now.

Comment: Or, you could *post some markup*, and get help, whatever !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate event handlers with loop in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487366/how-to-generate-event-handlers-with-loop-in-javascript)

Comment: Added html code. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to everyone here, as someone posted an instance of event handlers with loop, have added another function that handles the said event and it now works.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    (function(i){
        var btnSelector = ".dropdown:eq(" + i + ") .dropbtn";
        var drpSelector = ".dropdown:eq(" + i + ") .dropdown-content";

        $(btnSelector).on("click", function(event){
            if($(drpSelector).is(":visible")){
                $(drpSelector).hide();
            }
            else{
                $(drpSelector).show();
            }
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something in the lines of:

```
$(".dropbtn").on("click", function(event){
    $(this).siblings('.dropdown-content').toggle();
});
```

It would catch a click on any `.dropbtn`, find the sibling with the class `.dropdown-content` and show/hide it.

Comment: @BengeminUy I tested in a fiddle if what I posted would work, and it did, maybe you want to try it and, if you liked it, accept my answer? :P