# Single separated scroll bar instead of 3 tables scroll bars

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to unite 3 scroll bars into one? I have method written down below that connects one bar, but how do i do that to connect more than one? Table can have different width. I tried to loop through tables and use `+=` operator on `scrollWrapper`, thinking it has some kind of array or list that can contain single scroll event, but it seems it is not.

```js
let tables = document.querySelectorAll(".table");
let scrollWrapper = document.querySelector(".scroll-bar");
let scrollBar = scrollWrapper.querySelector(".bar");

scrollBar.setAttribute("style", "width: 2000px;");

scrollWrapper.onscroll = function()
{
  tables[2].scrollLeft = scrollWrapper.scrollLeft;
}
tables[2].onscroll = function()
{
  scrollWrapper.scrollLeft = tables[2].scrollLeft;
}
```

```css
.main {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
}

.table {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.table table{
  width: 1000px;
}

.table th,
.table td{
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.scroll-bar {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.scroll-bar .bar {
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  
  <div class="wrapper">
    
    <div class="table">
      
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      
    </div>
      <div class="table">
      
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      
    </div>
     <div class="table">
      
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="scroll-bar">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use a loop over the tables, and then set the `onscroll` within the loop? At the moment you are only applying it to `tables[2]`, but you want to apply it to `tables[i]` for `i` in `tables.length`.

Comment: @BillyBrown It will apply event only for the last one.

Comment: You can use a function to capture the index: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6487376/1406083

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've wrapped your `tables[2].scrollleft` into a forloop to select all tables.

```js
let tables = document.querySelectorAll(".table");
let scrollWrapper = document.querySelector(".scroll-bar");
let scrollBar = scrollWrapper.querySelector(".bar");

scrollBar.setAttribute("style", "width: 2000px;");

scrollWrapper.onscroll = function()
{
  for (i = 0; i < tables.length; i++){
    tables[i].scrollLeft = scrollWrapper.scrollLeft;
  }
}
```

```css
.main {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
}

.table {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.table table{
  width: 1000px;
}

.table th,
.table td{
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.scroll-bar {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.scroll-bar .bar {
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  
  <div class="wrapper">
    
    <div class="table">
      
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      
    </div>
      <div class="table">
      
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      
    </div>
     <div class="table">
      
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="scroll-bar">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to loop through each scrolling elements

possible example to start from

```js
let tables = document.querySelectorAll(".table");
let scrollWrapper = document.querySelector(".scroll-bar");
let scrollBar = scrollWrapper.querySelector(".bar");

scrollBar.setAttribute("style", "width: 2000px;");

scrollWrapper.onscroll = function() {
  for (i = 0; tables.length; i++) {
    tables[i].scrollLeft = scrollWrapper.scrollLeft;
  }
}


for (i = 0; tables.length; i++) {
  tables[i].onscroll = function() {
    scrollWrapper.scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
  }
}
```

```css
.main {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
}

.table {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.table table {
  width: 1000px;
}

.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.scroll-bar {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.scroll-bar .bar {
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="table">

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
    <div class="table">

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
    <div class="table">

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
            <th>Some header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
            <td>Some text</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="scroll-bar">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what is needed.

You can achieve this with css.

Remove

```
.table {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

and add

```
.wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    position: relative;
}
```

Than you can manipulate scroll in javascript.

Comment: it will scroll whole parent box. I needed only table. Imagine you have title above table.